# greping two different things from a tail command

Tags: perl, grep, tail

Is there a way to grep 2 instances of one word or 1 instance of another word in a single cmd line with perl (perl is a must)

I am trying to do a tail -f file | grep -m 2 word_x OR grep word_y

I am trying to catch word_x two times in the file, if that happens then the tail stops. 
But word_x doesnt always appear, so i like to have another word_y to stop the tail command.

if word_x appears 2 or more times abort the tail;
if word_x appears only 1 time, look for one ocurrance of word_y and abort the tail;
if word_x doesnt appear but word y appears abort the tail;

Word_y is the last word that will always appear on my file.

So it can be like this 3 examples

text
text
word_x 
text
word_x
test
word_y

text
text
text
word_x
test
word_y

text
text
text
word_y

I need to tail the file. i can use other command it doesnt need to be grep.

Is this possible? i have tried several things but cant come with a simple solution, maybe its not possible to do it on a single command line instruction.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a few lines of concise, testable sample input and expected output. If you mean `tail -f` instead of `tail` then be sure to state that - it's a very important distinction.

Comment: Also, do you want whole words. (e.g. if `abc` was a word, can `abcd xyz` be a match or only `abc xyz`). The more you specify this, the better the results will be

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with Perl?

Comment: @MarkSetchell When I've seen similar shell pipeline/filter questions, the OP sometimes specifies that they have a particular utility in mind to implement the solution in (e.g. `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`) and the question gets tagged with it. Here, OP stated that several things were tried [as a replacement for the `grep`] and I presume a perl script was one of them and the preferred solution is to be written in perl (e.g. `tail file | perl ...`). I've see OPs [try to] do `sed` filters [tagged] but `sed` just can't do it and they get an `awk` answer and are perfectly happy with it.

Comment: EdMorton i have edited the original, thanks i mean tail -f.

CraigEstey you got it right.


im looking for a simple line solution, i will create an script if a single line is not possible. And yes awk is fine if it can be done with it.

Comment: @AllanOrozco - put an `@` in front of someones name if you want them to be notified of a comment you direct to them. You haven't told us what you mean by `word` - does `word_x7` match `word_x` or not? If `word_x` appeared once on line 3 and then once on line 5 (as opposed to twice on one line), should the script abort or not?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample input/output it's a guess but it SOUNDS like this is what you're looking for:

```
tail file | awk '{x+=gsub(/word_x/,"&")} x==2||/word_y/{exit} 1'
```

Depending on the requirements you haven't shared with us yet, you may need word boundaries too, e.g. with GNU awk:

```
tail file | awk '{x+=gsub(/\<word_x\>/,"&")} x==2||/\<word_y\>/{exit} 1'
```

If you only want to consider cases where `word_x` occurs twice **on one line** then it's briefer:

```
tail file | awk 'gsub(/\<word_x\>/,"&")==2||/\<word_y\>/{exit} 1'
```

Comment: This seem to be what i was looking for, thanks i will give it a try once i get back to my dev machine

Comment: Based on Allan's edit, it looks like the word frequencies have to be on a per line basis. Thus, for a sequence `word1 able`, `word1 baker`, `word2 charlie`, your command aborts on baker instead of charlie. Allan, can you confirm/clarify this?

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks for the heads up I actually read the sample differently and there was a bug in my script where I was counting the number of lines that contain word1 instead of the number of occurrences of word1 and so when word1 occurred twice on a line I was only counting it once. I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) if word_x appears 2 or more times abort the tail

That's clear. But, the following is inconsistent

> (2) if word_x appears only 1 time, look for word_y

This says look for `word_y` only if the line has a single occurence of `word_x`

> (3) and abort the tail if word_x doesnt appear but word y appears abort the tail

However, this says only look for `word_y` if `word_x` does *not* appear.

(2) and (3) appear to conflict. To me, ignoring (2) and using (3) makes the most sense.

Also, you didn't say whether you wanted the "abort" line to be passed on or not.

Here's some code that I believe will work. I did some minimal testing on it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my($word_x) = shift(@ARGV);
my($word_y) = shift(@ARGV);

# quirk of perl -- the regex needs the longest to be first in order if had
# similar words like "abc" and "abcd"
my(@rgx) = ($word_x,$word_y);
@rgx = sort({length($b) <=> length($a)} @rgx);
my($rgx) = join("|",@rgx);

while (my $buf = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($buf);

    # NOTE: this assumes the "abort" line should be printed
    print($buf,"\n");

    # get frequency of each word
    # NOTE: this grabs partials, so it may need \b or \W wrappers
    my(%freq);
    while ($buf =~ /($rgx)/go) {
        $freq{$1} += 1;
    }

    my $xcnt = $freq{$word_x};

    # got two or more of x -- we're done
    last if ($xcnt >= 2);

    # only look for y if x does _not_ appear at all
    if ($xcnt == 0) {
        # found a y -- we're done
        last if ($freq{$word_y} >= 1);
    }

    # NOTE: this assumes the "abort" line should _not_ be printed
    # use either of the prints but _not_ both
    ###print($buf,"\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, ill try something like that code thanks. BTW I have edited the original post, what i am looking to do is a single cmd line call, i wondering is that is possible with out doing a new script.

Comment: Thanks for edit. To clarify, your new rule (2) implies that `text x text y y` should _not_ match because it has _one_ `x`and needs _one_ `y` whereas this line has _two_ `y`s? If not, only (1) and (3) are needed as (3) covers (2). Notice that both my script and Ed's are using hashes for word freq, so something simpler might not be possible. With perl, it can invoke the `tail -f` in a pipe internally, so `script word_x word_y [ifile]` and _no_ shell pipe for `tail -f file | script` needed. Sounds like you want only whole words to match? If so, my regex is wrong and the script can be simplified